# Unable(?) to delete Search Service Application

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server

Good morning. I am using SP2013 on Windows 2012.

My application server failed, but I had access to CA on a web front end server, so as per recommendations, I started services for my service applications, though I noticed Search wasn't working. It was still looking to APP1. That's okay..... someone had told me that some ends needed to be tied with Search and User Profile (I don't use UPA, though), and if I didn't have a lot of information, I could just recreate Search.

Which is what I've been trying, but I'm having difficulty deleting the old Search. I tried to delete it using UI: Go to CA, highlight the SA and click DELETE. No response for such a long time, so then I tried:

```
stsadm.exe -o RemoveConfigurationObject <GUID>
```

Or something along the lines of that... I don't quite remember. It ran for hours and hours. Stupidly, I did not use -Verbose, so I didn't know if anything was still working. That was a mistake on my part.

Are there any other recommendations for deleting the old SSA? Should I just leave it be if it's technically not doing anything and create a new SSA? I tried that while waiting, and creating a SSA is also taking a very long time (currently at ~40 minutes).

Edit: I noticed that the command removed the Proxy - that's gone now. But everything else is still there, I think.

Update!: I had revived my application server with some technical CPR (haha), but jokes aside, the server will not last. On the application server, I was able to access Central Administration to delete the SSA immediately (whereas if I use the same account on my web front end, it will time out and not proceed). Since I figured I had nothing to lose, I shut down my fail(ing) application server and tried to move the search topology (clone and set), but when I ran:

```
Set-SPSearchTopology -Identity $clone
```

(This was run after creating new components and adding it to the topology, etc. with PowerShell). It said it couldn't connect to the original machine. This was yesterday at the end of the day, so again I stupidly did not write down the error. It couldn't connect - well - because I had shut down my APP server instead of waiting for it to go out again. Is there a way to force this?

I also tried to clear the configuration cache, as recommended below.

Comment: Clear the Config cache on the servers(all servers in farm), restart the server and then try again.

Comment: It didn't quite work. I found a way to bring back my old application server, though it's a little rough, and could delete almost immediately in CA. So as a conceptual question: Why can I not delete it on the web front end, but I can delete it on the original application server (this app server acted as the 'seed' for the farm and has the original CA). I am using the same accounts.....